# How to select integrated graphic card over NVIDIA?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics

I am using Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon version (based on Ubuntu 16.04, but I was told I can't post in askubuntu).

I have Intel CPU with integrated graphics and NVIDIA 1060.

In BIOS I have enabled integrated grahpic card and set it as default. Monitors are connected to integrated card. NVIDIA is going to be used only for cryptocurrency mining. I tried to use it as display, but everything is jerky, I need to use integrated card for using the PC.

I have installed these drivers: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
I chose Ubuntu 16.04 version.

Now my desktop doesn't work. It doesn't show anything, but if I plug in monitor into graphic card, then everything works fine.

It seems somehow NVIDIA drivers are now used by default. How do I get back integrated graphic card to be used by desktop?

```
inxi -Fxz
Grahpics: Card-1: Intel Device 5912 bus-ID: 00:02.0
               Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1c03 bus-ID: 01:00.0
               Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia tty size: 240x67 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
```

UPDATE: I have used some gui to switch drivers back on to open source drivers, but now claymores miner says: `No AMD OPENCL or NVIDIA CUDA GPUs found, exit`

Comment: I am not really sure what's not working when you say "My desktop doesn't work" but this answer of mine will be related or might be helpful to get back your system up.  (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328872/70728) This doesn't really answer your question might be related.

Comment: Also we need more information like, What's really not working? Which NVIDIA drivers are being installed(Third party or distribution provided one)? `dmesg` logs and your xorg configuration file.

Comment: @Thushi - I have updated the question.